# using ")" within if/else statements in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

Here's the snippet which doesn't work as expected:

```
set MYMACHINENAME=BuildmasterW32

if "%MYMACHINENAME%"=="BuildmasterW32" (
    set PROGRAMFILESDIR=D:\Program Files
    set WISEDIR=D:\Program Files\Wise Installation Studio\WiseScript Package Editor
) 

if "%MYMACHINENAME%"=="BuildmasterW64" (
    set PROGRAMFILESDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)
    set WISEDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Wise Installation Studio\WiseScript Package Editor"
)

set WISEDIR
rem we see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Wise Installation Studio\WiseScript Package Editor` at this point
pause
```

I'd expect to see `D:\Program Files...` value instead.

The reason is that the closing parenthesis in the previous line, which sets PROGRAMFILESDIR, closes the conditional statement and the value of WISEDIR gets overwritten.

If I enclose the value for PROGRAMFILESDIR with double quotes, the code works right, BUT PROGRAMFILESDIR becomes equal to `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` (the quotes go to the variable) and not `C:\Program Files (x86)` as I need. That's not what I want because PROGRAMFILESDIR is a prefix, to which relative paths are added later, so there must be no quotes in the value.

I tried to add a backslash before `)` in the PROGRAMFILESDIR assignment line, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there any solution within the snippet that I have provided, or I would have to rewrite it to use goto instead of if/else ?

Comment: The better answer is the one MC ND posted.  That way you do not have to escape the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis:

```
if /i "%MYMACHINENAME%"=="BuildmasterW64" (
    set PROGRAMFILESDIR=C:\Program Files ^(x86^)
    set WISEDIR="C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\Wise Installation Studio\WiseScript Package Editor"
    )
```

Oh, and add **/I** to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you for pointing at the escape character. I didn't know the correct escape char ... Accepting this answer as an easier to use one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of quoting the value, quote the assignment operation

```dos
set "MYMACHINENAME=BuildmasterW32"

if "%MYMACHINENAME%"=="BuildmasterW32" (
    set "PROGRAMFILESDIR=D:\Program Files"
    set "WISEDIR=D:\Program Files\Wise Installation Studio\WiseScript Package Editor"
) 

if "%MYMACHINENAME%"=="BuildmasterW64" (
    set "PROGRAMFILESDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)"
    set "WISEDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Wise Installation Studio\WiseScript Package Editor"
)

set WISEDIR
pause
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried quoting the complete line (including set command) but that didn't work. Didn't try quoting the parameter... The interesting fact is that if I quote just the first assignments (PROGRAMFILESDIR), the whole construct doesn't work at all, producing mysterious and seemingly unrelated error. So I need to quote every call to set.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoS, It is a good practice to *always* quote the assignments (unless there is a reason not to do it). Not only it protects against most of the problematic characters but also it ensures there are not spaces at the end of the stored value. In your case, you have two lines that *need* to be quoted (those with a parenthesis in the value), not one.

Comment: Well, I needed to quote all four set calls for the snippet to work. As missing the needed quotes leads to strange errors, I find the quoting approach to be error-prone. And, frankly speaking, I never in my 30-year practice needed to quote set calls (and hopefully never will :).

Comment: But I admit that an extra space at the end did happen sometimes for me, and caused minor troubles (quickly discovered, though).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoS, you don't quote the SET command. You quote the variable name all the way to the end of your assignment.  If it did not work for you, then you are doing something wrong.